# OpenCart: Renaming the tabs on the welcome module

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

I'm using the "Welcome" module to insert custom html within different sections of my website. Is it possible to rename the tabs so I can find my modules easier?

Right now, when I view my welcome module, the content is organized as "Module 1", "Module 2", "Module 3", etc. I'd like to give these tabs custom name so I can find my content faster. Something like "Homepage Facebook Announcement", "Product Shipping Information", etc.

Version used: v1.5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it won't be easy, currently these names are not stored in database, this module 1 , module 2 names come from welcome.tpl file, there is a variable `$module_row` which increments foreach module like `$module_row++` and the name is just shown like `echo $tab_module . ' ' . $module_row;`

if you really want it, you can add a new column in `setting` table and store your module name there, but then you will have to edit your `getSetting()` function too....

its kind of complex and not advisable if you don't what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You'd think why this hasn't been implemented by default for this module. :) I guess I'll leave it alone as you suggested.

Comment: @farjam i don't think it will implemented in near future, its one of the last things oc developers will worry about, i mean people rarely edit welcome module, and you can click on module 1 etc to see its content without reloading the page, its not too bad.

Comment: Just curious, do you know of any other OC module that would give me the possibility of creating random html blocks that I can place in different sections of my pages?